# Django Rest Framework/Angular JS Preflight options

Tags: django, angularjs, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

My application uses DRF for backend and consuming APIs with AngularJS.
For some particular APIs I am facing following issue.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8000/someurl`. The request was redirected to `'http://localhost:8000/someurl/'`, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I am using django-cors-headers and I have already ensured my settings.

- Cors origin is allowed for all.
- `Append_slash` is set to True.
- `CORS_PREFLIGHT_MAX_AGE` is set.
- cors header middleware is set appropriately.

Front end server is running on localhost:3000.
Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have got a reasonable finding for the issue. Might be helpful for others someday.
AngularJS $resource removes '/' from the URL. And preflight OPTIONS request for URL `'http://localhost:8000/someURL'` was getting redirected to `'http://localhost:8000/someURL/'` because django APPENDS_SLASH by defaults. Hence preflight request was getting redirected.

Either I need to force $resource to not remove '/' from URL or force django to `APPEND_SLASH = False` and update my URLs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer works for me. Added {stripTrailingSlashes: false} to $resource config and everything is fine.